# Questions on Salting Technique to counter Skew Joins in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I work with Spark SQL queries, and I am trying to understand the **implementation** of **Salting** technique to tackle skewed `Joins` in Spark SQL. After searching the internet, I found [this](https://dzone.com/articles/why-your-spark-apps-are-slow-or-failing-part-ii-da) article that discusses the same. I did understand the overall concept but I'm unable to grasp few parts regarding it's implementation as described in the article.

Here are few questions -

Part 1 (salting the Fact) -

```
val salted_fact_df = spark.sql("""
                              | select 
                              | concat(key, '_', FLOOR(RAND(123456) * 19)) as SALTED_KEY, val
                              | from fact_table
                              |"""
                              | )
```

- In the above code, what does the seed value `123456` signify ? Can I use a different value say `1000` ? Then how will the output differ in that case ? Is it
  mandatory to provide the seed value for this to work correctly ? Or
  can I just use the `RAND()` without a seed ?
- What is the significance of multiplying `19` with the random value ?
  Then in this case what distinct `bucket` numbers will be generated ? Is it `0` -
  `18` or `0` - `19` ?

Part 2 (replicating the dim) -

```
val exploded_dim_df = spark.sql("""
                               | select dim_key, val, 
                               | explode(array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)) as salted_key
                               | from dim_table
                               |"""
                               |)
```

- Why is value `19` being used to replicate the smaller (dim) table ? I
  thought the expression `rand(123456) * 19` (shown before) would
  result in values only from `0`-`18`, then what's the use of
  `19` as this value would never occur during the generation of the `salt`-ed keys for the `fact` table shown before ? In
  other words, a salted key such as `key_19` would never generate while
  salting the fact table. Please correct my understanding.
- As seen above, in order to replicate the smaller table N times, all
  the distinct values in the range are being hardcoded (e.g.
  `array(0,1,2...N)`) in the code. So, if I have a bigger table
  and decide to go with a larger bucket number, say `100`, then
  hardcoding all the 100 distinct values in the code would make it
  rather clumsy. So is there any shorter/smarter way to specify the
  range in the sql query without hardcoding all the distinct numbers ?

Can anyone please help me to answer the above questions. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers !

Comment: What Spark version are you using? Spark 3 handles skew joins automatically: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/whats-new-apache-spark-3-join-skew-optimization/read

Comment: Hi Alex.. i am using Spark 2.4.6. But unfortunately, it doesn't have skewed join optimizations like Spark 3